# data frame names as word in quotation mark

Tags: r

I have two part question, both concerns working with data frames names:

1. I want to concatenate two dfs names with separator, for example: `df1` and `df2` to be `"df1_&_df2"`
2. I want  make R to read data frame name as character in quotation marks so my df is called `df1` and I in certain parts of my code I want it to be `"df1"`.

When it come to 1st part I tried `paste` but it pasted entire data in both dfs and `names` concerns column names.

In the 2nd issue, being able to make R understand df name as quotation marked word is very handy in code for more complex charts, I simply put dfs into code and R makes chart title out of it. I understand there is very simple workaround here, I can create list of names manually  `list=c("df1", "df2")` and then just use function `get` in places where I need to refer to content of data frame instead of its name, but it seems little inconvenient in the long run. Is there any function in R which output is just df name? Something that looks like GiveMeName(df) and the output is "df"? (I wrote this in normal font intentionally, so no one would thought this is real function)

Comment: Take a look at `quote` or `substitute`.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you'll have to give a use case for me to understand your goal.

For #2, you can use `deparse(substitute(df1))`.  Here's an example:

```
plot_and_title <- function(df1) {
  data_name <- deparse(substitute(df1))
  plot(df1[[1]], df1[[2]], main = data_name)
}

plot_and_title(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answer by @Nathan Werth, you can concatenate names using:

```
paste(deparse(substitute(df1)), deparse(substitute(df2)), sep="_&_")
```